# Android webview with fcm

Tags: java, android, web, webview

I have a website and I made FCM instant notifications with Google Firebase. Notifications working ok.
I want to make an android application that will just open the site as an application and publish it on Google Play.
I tried to do with a webviewer, the site work ok but I do not receive notifications and he don't ask for access.

Could someone give me some ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a whole process to get Notification Push on your android application, you cannot receive (on the mobile app) the same way you receive the notification on your website.

See for more information : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: then would it be easier to do PWA?

Comment: I don't know enough on PWA to help you but setting up FCM on android is not that hard.